# Python Cursor SELECT columns dynamically

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to access to a MySql database directly, although I am using Django 1.6.1 and
I know that it is easier using Django Models, I need to use cursors.
Something like this:

```
columnList = ['Field1', 'Field2']
cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM table", [columnList])
```

But I am getting this exception: `(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

How can I pass to the execute cursor function a dinamic column list?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to use cursors?

Comment: Because is much more faster than django querysets (http://www.slideshare.net/OReillyOSCON/unbreaking-your-django-application slide 55)

Comment: Have you already figured out that's where the problem is? You can't know if its faster unless you have measured it for your application. So I am curious to know now what is the ORM query that you tried that isn't preforming to your liking for which you want to drop down to executing raw queries.

Comment: It is a query that retrieve 160000 rows of 700 columns. With my ORM query it takes 350s, with the raw query i wrote down 200s. It is not the best I've done, but... At least is a 42% faster.

Comment: Please post your ORM query and how you are measuring it; because 160,000 rows is a small number.

Comment: 160000 is small, but 700 cols is a bit huge:

`qs = MyModel.objects.filter( Date__lte=date2,Date__gte=date1,id__in=ids ).values_list(*columnList)`
Then, I just use it in a for loop: `for obj in qs:`
`print obj`

Comment: Your model has 700 columns? That's a new one. Either way, you should be using `only` and not `values_list`.

Comment: I finally got down to 250 columns, but this is the most I can do.
About the values_list is because I take this list to write it directly into a xlsx (with openpyxl optimized writing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I built a string with all the elements in the list, and I passed this string to the query string:

```
columnList = ['Field1', 'Field2']

for idx, field in enumerate(columnList):
    if idx != len(columnList)-1:
        listFields += field + ', '
    else:
        listFields += field

cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM table", listFields)
```

This is not what I was looking for, and... I am not proud of it..., but even like this is faster than iterate a django queryset

Comment: You could have used: `cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM table", ",".join(columnList))`

Answer (score 2):

Only one list is expected as second argument in the current form of `execute` but you are passing a list within a list. Try this:

```
columnList = ['Field1', 'Field2']
cursor.execute("SELECT %s, %s FROM table", columnList)
```

Comment: So I need to know how many columns I want previously? I don't have this information... But thanks a lot!

Comment: Ideally, yes. Django needs to automatically escape each parameter to prevent SQL injection attacks.